# Sharepoint JSON formatting - show button A or B

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I want to show button A or button B in a column depending on value in another column.

one button should start a flow, another button should launch a hyperlink also I need to add other buttons.

I have spent the day googling and fudging and the current code shows nothing, if I remove the code for button B then button A works.

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "button",
            "txtContent": "New ",
            "customRowAction": {
                "action": "executeFlow",
                "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"be40d280-88df9a875fa\"}"
            },
            "style": {
                "display": "=if(  ([$Kent] == 'A' ), 'block', 'none')"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "button",
            "txtContent": "New",
            "attributes": {
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "='URL'"
            },
            "style": {
                "display": "=if(([$Kent] == 'B'), 'block', 'none')"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, while it creates either a button or a hyperlink, as buttons cant work as hyperlink. But the issue was the syntax of the "href" tag. All the googling i have done showed it to be written as  "href": "=' URL '" which must have thrown some error which made the entire column blank. When i changed it to "href": "http://www.google.dk"  it worked.

```
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "New ",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"}"
  },

"style":{
  "display": "=if(  ([$Kent] == 'A' ), 'block', 'none')"
}
},

{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "New",
  "attributes": {
   "target": "_blank",
   "href": "https://www.google.dk"
},

"style":{
  "display": "=if(([$Kent] == 'B'), 'block', 'none')"
},
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below JSON code, it should work for you:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "button",
            "txtContent": "New ",
            "customRowAction": {
                "action": "executeFlow",
                "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"be40d280-88df9a875fa\"}"
            },
            "style": {
                "display": "=if([$Kent] == 'A', 'block', 'none')"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "New",
            "attributes": {
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "https://www.google.com"
            },
            "style": {
                "display": "=if([$Kent] == 'B', 'block', 'none')"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried splitting them up in separate columns, button A works but button B doesnt show if i have an URL in "href" "=' ...   ' "   ´´´{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "NY",
      
"attributes": {
"target": "_blank",
"href": "='https://www.google.dk'"
}

}´´´´

Comment: if i strip http://www.  and just use "href": "='google.dk'" the resulting link is "https://my sharepoint site/'google.dk'  "

Comment: okay so figured out the HREF part, apparently i need to use a different syntax than everyone else.  "href": "http://www.google.dk"  works. Gonna rewrite the orignal code and see if thats whats been messing with it.

Comment: Yes, if you are hard coding the link then you don't need to use `=` in href (you can simply pass your link as a string). You need to use `=` only if you are adding any `if` condition or any other expression which is returning the link based on conditions.

Comment: However, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way to solve this issue.